# tensorflow_model_server Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: cors, tensorflow-serving

I would like to set up a TensorFlow Serving endpoint which can be accessed like an API from a **different origin domain**. I have exported my model successfully, and I can get predictions via POST requests in curl. However, when I try to get predictions in the browser, the request is blocked because TensorFlow Serving does not return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

I am using the `tensorflow/serving` docker image as instructed at https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker. (I know this uses `tensorflow_model_serving` internally, which in turn is built on top of gRPC.)

Here is the error from Chrome:

```
Failed to load http://<TensorFlow Serving Domain>/v1/models/<Model Name>:predict: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

So, is there any way to get TensorFlow Serving to return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Comment: How did you solve this eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment. You might want to consider having a proxy handle the requests, so it can conform to your environment. That will also allow load balancing, URL rewriting, secure connections, etc. as you may need.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue when I was trying to call the predict API of TensorFlow-serving from JS (using fetch command). I could not find any way online, to edit CORS settings of Tensorflow-Serving itself.

**Solution:**

I could resolve the issue by adding one more layer of Flask as a backend

So the final architecture becomes something like this:

> HTML + JS  <--->  Flask  <--->  Tensorflow Serving (Docker)

The Flask backend then calls Tensorflow Serving API using a library like `requests`.
This additional layer could be also used for preprocessing of the input in Python (if needed).

And the code would look something like:

1. JS (Frontend):

```js
await fetch("http://<localhost/website-name>/predict", settings).then(response => response.json()).then(
   function (response) {
       console.log("Prediction response: ", response)
   })
```

2. Flask (backend):

```py
@app.route("/predict", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    data = loads(request.data.decode(encoding="ascii"))

    # Do something with data, maybe preprocessing

    raw = "{\"instances\":[["
    for key, value in data.items():
        raw = raw + data[key] + ","
    raw = raw[:-1]
    raw = raw + "]]}"
    print(raw)

    url = "http://<TensorFlow Serving Domain>/v1/models/<Model Name>:predict"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=raw)
    res_json=response.json()
    return res_json
```

I have used this in one of my projects here: [Link](https://github.com/mstale007/Incremental_Model_Kafka)

Feel free to check it out!

Answer (score 0):

For dev, you can use a Chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) to disable the annoying CORS checks.

For production, you need to use nginx/envoy or the like to proxy the request to TF Serving.